# How to specify needed fields using Beautiful Soup and properly call upon website elements using HTML tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to create a web scraping program that will return the values of the Title, Company, and Location from job cards on Indeed. I finally am not returning error codes, however, I am only returning one value for each of the desired fields when there are multiple job cards I am attempting to call on. Also, the value for the company field is returning the value for the title field because  is used there as well in the HTML code. I am unfamiliar with HTML code or how to specify my needs using Beautiful Soup. I have tried to use the documentation and played with a few different methods to solve this problem, but have been unsuccessful.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://au.indeed.com/jobs? 
q=web%20developer&l=perth&from=searchOnHP&vjk=6c6cd45320143cdf").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

results = soup.find(id="mosaic-zone-jobcards")
job_elements = results.find("div", class_="slider_container")

for job_element in job_elements:
    title = job_element.find("h2")
    company = job_element.find("span")
    location = job_element.find("div", class_="companyLocation")
print(title.text)
print(company.text)
print(location.text)
```

Here is what returns to the console:

```
C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\WebScraper1\venv\Scripts\python.exe 
C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/WebScraper1/Indeed.py
Web App Developer
Web App Developer
Perth WA 6000

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Even simple print debugging might help here...

Answer (score 0):

`job_elements` only returns the first matching element because you used `find` instead of `find_all`. For the same reason `company` links to the first `span` found in `div.slider_container`. The `span` you want contains `class="companyName"`. Also, the prints should be inside the for loop. Here's the improved code.

```
job_elements = results.find_all("div", class_="slider_container")

for job_element in job_elements:
    title = job_element.find("h2")
    company = job_element.find("span", class_="companyName")
    location = job_element.find("div", class_="companyLocation")
    print(title.text)
    print(company.text)
    print(location.text)
```